# How can I write a factorial based on the number?

Tags: python, list, function

So I;m trying to write a function `file(s:int, filn:str)` -> None that writes the value of n! to a file with the specified filename.

n! is n the number to the extent which the factorial will be calculated.

For example:

```
file(10, 'test.out')
# test.out
3628800
```

Here is my attempt at the code so far, which clearly doesn't work at all, what should I change?

```
filn = 100

def file(s:int, filn:str):
    s = open(filn)
    q = s.read()
    for i in range(1,s+1):
        return (q * i)

print(file(10, 'data'))
```

Comment: Why would you put the file inside a range?

Comment: `s` is a File-like object so you can't do `s+1`.

Comment: Your function accepts `s` as an argument, and then immediately overwrites `s` with the file handle.

Comment: Why are you reading from a file that you intend to *write* to?

Comment: Most obvious problem is that there is nowhere you write to the file... then it might not work because you don't close the file... and then you're returning the first iteration through your loop... I strongly suggest you try and calculate a factorial _without_ involving files at all first, and only then try to change it to write to a file

Comment: In general, write *small* functions that are easy to test first. It's generally easier to inline smaller working functions into a single large function (if necessary for performance) that it is to pick apart a single large function looking for errors.

Comment: Define `factorial(n: int) -> int` and `write_to_file(n: int, s: str)` that uses `factorial`.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate factorial value and when write it into a file.

```py
def file(x: int, file_name: str) -> None:
    factorial = 1
    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        factorial *= i
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(factorial))
```

This function writes value of `x!` into file with `file_name` name.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you insist on calculating the factorial yourself, you should probably also use the math library for efficiency.

Using Ratery's answer with the math library:

```
from math import factorial

def file(x: int, file_name: str) -> None:
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(factorial(x)))
```